# AppleScript : create a list, then create a URL with items

Tags: list, applescript

I need to create a list of number 
E.g of text value `55774455,114455777,11445544`

And the result will be :

```
https://url.com/url/data=55774455%20OR%data=114455777%20OR%data=11445544
```

The challenge for me it the number of data is unknown but I guess I can count the list first with something like

set listSize to count of fatalist ##

I just can't think right now

Comment: That's not a valid URL. Maybe you mean `https://url.com/url?data1=55774455&data2=114455777&data3=11445544`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know I can't provide the actual url for privacy, but the idea is to have the different variables in a loop, after the domain like data=55774455%%20OR%20data=555677445%20OR%20data=342342423 and so on depending the number of variable (the long numbers are the variables) basically it's doing a search with all this data.

Comment: I guess I have to make a new list with "%20OR%" + the number, and without any space or line in between, but that will make a error for the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
property base : "https://example.com/"

on run argv
    set input1 to "55774455,114455777,11445544"
    set input1 to my string2list(",", input1)

    set input2 to "55774455 114455777 11445544" -- if input format can change
    set input2 to input2's words

    set output1 to base & "data=" & my list2string("%20OR%20data=", input2)

    set input1_ to input1's items -- for test

    repeat with |item| in input1
        set |item|'s contents to "data=" & |item|
    end repeat
    set output2 to base & "" & my list2string("%20OR%20", input1)

    {¬
        return, input1_, ¬
        return, input1_ = input2, ¬
        return, input2, ¬
        return, output1, ¬
        return, output1 = output2, ¬
        return, output2}
end run

on list2string(delimiter, source) -- general utility
    try
        set {|applescript's text item delimiters|, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, delimiter}
        set |result| to source as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
    on error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
        error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    end try
    |result|
end list2string

on string2list(delimiter, source) -- general utility
    try
        set {|applescript's text item delimiters|, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, delimiter}
        set |result| to source's text items
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
    on error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to |applescript's text item delimiters|
        error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    end try
    |result|
end string2list
```

produces `https://example.com/data=55774455%20OR%20data=114455777%20OR%20data=11445544` (in different ways).

Comment: That look perfect thank you ! I only changed the way the data are collected (using a dialog for now) but I always getting a message whatever I do "Can’t set item 1 of "55774455,114455777,11445544" to "data=5"."

Comment: @KevinCork I had overlooked your input format. Updated the answer to hopefully solve the issue.